# How can I setup an entity with two foreign keys to itself?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity that has two foreign keys to it's own table. This is what it looks like:

```
public class SystemUser : BaseModel
{
    [Column("SystemUserId")]
    public override Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public Guid? MobilePhoneProviderId { get; set; }
    public virtual MobilePhoneProvider MobilePhoneProvider { get; set; }
    public Guid? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUser Manager { get; set; }
    public Guid? AdminAssistantId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUser AdminAssistant { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool SendEmail { get; set; }

    public string FinaleUsername { get; set; }
    public string FinalePassword { get; set; }
    public int? FloatUserId { get; set; }

    public Guid? SystemUserTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUserType SystemUserType { get; set; }
    public Guid? SystemUserJobFunctionId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUserJobFunction SystemUserJobFunction { get; set; }
    public Guid? SystemUserJobRoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUserJobRole SystemUserJobRole { get; set; }
    public Guid? SystemUserLocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUserLocation SystemUserLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SystemUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `AdminAssistant` and `Manager` properties. However it is giving me the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'SystemUser' and 'SystemUser'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.

If I remove one of them (either one, it doesn't matter which), it works fine but for some reason it is getting confused about having both. I tried adding the `ForeignKey` attributes on each as well as using the fluent API to configure it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Manager)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ManagerId);

modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.AdminAssistant)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.AdminAssistantId);
```

Neither worked. Is there any way I can do this?

FYI I'm not using Code First. I'm writing the database script manually and just using EF as an ORM. Not sure if that information is relevant but I thought I'd give it anyways.

Comment: Does making the Id property a primary key help? e.g `[Key, Column("SystemUserId")]`

Comment: No that didn't help. The `BaseModel` has a property of ID that is being overridden and it has a Key attribute on it so it's already being set.

Comment: Not an answer, but it might be cleaner to model these relationships in a separate table. That way you can have one-to-many relationships, inverse relationships (find subordinates), and other relationships in the future (e.g. former manager). You can also add attributes like date started, date ended, ... and treat the relationship itself as an entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you will want to include something like

```
ICollection<SystemUser> ManagedUsers {get; set;}
ICollection<SystemUser> AdminAssistedUsers {get; set;}
```

Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.Manager)
        .WithMany(x => x.ManagedUsers)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ManagerId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.AdminAssistant)
        .WithMany(x => x.AdminAssistedUsers)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.AdminAssistantId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: My guess is that OP is using EF 6, which it will likely need the collections on there to help model the relationship. I believe in EFCore this is not a requirement. If this works, and that relationship is meaningless, I would be inclined to not mark them as virtual and then never include them in the dbset queries

Comment: This does seem to work. Not super elegant but it's fine